# sqlite returns 0 rows

Tags: sqlite

```
SELECT   skill_name, character_name,  cb_id, cb_id2 FROM  characterbasics, characterskills WHERE  characterbasics.character_name = 'Joe' & characterbasics.cb_id =  characterskills.cb_id2
```

This, for some reason, returns 0 rows

The character name is in there (as well as 2 other dummy names).. and both cbid and cbid2 are the same.
When i try the query without the & cbid=cbid2 i get the name with the other data.. now when i check for JUST cbid=cbid2 i get 3 different dummy characters i created...
 im trying to pull all "skills" associated with one character by matching the id of the character name in table 1 with the character id in table 2

Where have I erred?
cn = character name

```
cn    cbid    cbid2
Joe   2         2
```

This is what it SHOULD look like..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use & as logical AND operator (& is binary operator), so sql should look like :

```
SELECT skill_name, character_name, cb_id, cb_id2 
FROM characterbasics, characterskills 
WHERE  characterbasics.character_name = 'Joe' AND characterbasics.cb_id =  characterskills.cb_id2
```

Comment: ...... wow.. ok that worked! Its been soo long since ive used any form of sql.. thank you